# dimens for different devices motoe2 and android one

Tags: android

I have two devices moto e2 [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VF1p.png) with density 244 and micromax android one [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V653R.png) with density 217 both of them fall in to hdpi bucket but moto e2 is 720p and other one is 480p screen sizes are same for both the devices. How to give different dimens for those case, what should be the buckets names in such case.

Comment: why giving them a different dimensions?

Comment: because the screens look different in both the devices in 480p device every thing is bigger compared to 720p

Comment: yes, and thats the default behaviour of android. you cannot do that thing since there are thousand of different android devices right now with different screen size(not the resolution) but the actual dimension of the screen

Comment: from what i saw in your screenshot, your layout cannot fit in the screen, you can make the container scrollable or adjust the dimension using the different resource folder: refer here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html